# How to change Mule log file size for Applications

Tags: logging, size, mule, logfile

I want to change the Log file size for the applications deployed. I see the following properties in wrapper.conf.

```
wrapper.logfile.maxsize=1m
wrapper.logfile.maxfiles=10
```

The changes to above properties only apply for mule.log, not application logs.

How can I change the log file size of applications? I am using mule ce 3.4.0.

Answer (score 2):

In order to change this you would need to deploy a log4j.properties (or log4j.xml) with each app and configure logging appropriately, initial per-app logging is hardcoded. You can as well create a patch with a different configuration for the appropriate logging but that is certainly not recommended and definitely more hardcore.

Comment: oh ok. We already do that for some of Mule applications. I was thinking it would be easier if there is a global setting. Thank You!